# How to document/mark a dead open source project?

Tags: discussion, tags

For a pet project I started researching for Object Databases. As such I stumbled [over db4o](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db4o). When digging into the topic a bit more, I stumbled over the fact that db4o got discontinued due to [the acquisition of Versant (the company behind the product) by Actian](http://supportservices.actian.com/versant/default.html)

> ## db4o
>
> With regret we have to announce that Actian decided not to actively pursue and promote the commercial db4o product offering for new customers any longer. Since the db4o dual licensing model allows for the free usage of the community edition of db4o for non-commercial purposes, you have the opportunity to continue to use it for your non-commercial applications or even fork it to provide support for the community.

Despite a [github repository](https://github.com/lytico/db4o) that still offers the sources there appears to be no active developed version or fork.

So, what to do with the tag?

At least it should be written down in [the tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/db4o/info) of db4o I suppose. But as I think this is not the first time a project ceases to exist, probably there is a well established way to handle this, I just did not find?

Comment: I'd suggest adding something like _"dbo4 has been discontinued due to <explanation with link>"_ to the tag.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

We did this with the [bukkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bukkit) tag:

> As of Aug 21, 2014 at 8:42 AM, [Bukkit has been discontinued](http://bukkit.org/threads/bukkit-its-time-to-say.305106/) and CraftBukkit (the actual server application) has been taken down due to DMCA requests.

Since Stack Overflow is not for the present, you should not burninate the tag.
Simply insert a note into the full tag wiki (not the excerpt).

Comment: I thought so. I just wondered if there is any other option, something like a very small skull within the tag would be cool. Then it would be obvious that when you are within such a tag that it is not healthy any more :)

Comment: So you're saying Bukkit kicked the bucket? *runs*

Comment: @cheffe I love skull idea--you should make it a feature request.

Comment: Or rename it [tag:db4o☠]

Comment: No, please, no skulls. At a first look, people won't understand it as dead tags.